# spark sql date interval sql query not working

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, sql-function

The objective I have is to show the data (sourced by a csv file) for every 15 minutes interval per day.

The solution I come up is a sql query which is creating the data I need:

```
select 
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, cast ([date] + ' ' + [time] as datetime2) ) / 15 * 15, 0) as dateInterval,
    SecurityDesc,
    StartPrice,
    SUM(CAST(TradedVolume as decimal(18,2))) as totalTradedVolume,
    SUM(cast(NumberOfTrades as int)) as totalNumberOfTrades,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, cast ([date] + ' ' + [time] as datetime) ) / 15 * 15, 0) ORDER BY Date) as rn
from MyTable
group by [date],[time],SecurityDesc,StartPrice
```

But once I want to use this in my Spark python code it complains about datediff/dateadd and even cast to datetime.

I understand its probably cant see the sql functions but I have imported:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime as d
from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff, to_date, lit
```

What should I do to make it work? I prefer to make my query work if not how in general I can show aggregated data for each 15 minutes in spark python?

UPDATE: looking to get data result something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have imported functions with an alias (which I think is a good practice) :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

This means you need to use the `F` variable to use imported functions like `F.to_date`. The functions you are using are SQL query functions and do not belong to the actual functions available in pyspark.sql.functions (see the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html) for the list of available functions)

To solve your issue in Spark I would use a dataFrame and then work on it to compute your results by using spark functions.

P.S next time, it's better to post the actual error message than stating that spark "complains" ;)